# Indiferencia entre Mayúsculas o Minúscula al buscar Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas Tengo este código,

```
NombreBanco = 'MiBanco'
NombreBanco2 = 'miBanco'
NombreBanco3 = 'mibanco'

if NombreBanco in Banco or NombreBanco2 in Banco or NombreBanco3 in Banco:
```

El Problema es que debo colocar por cada mayúscula o minúscula que necesite buscar, una nueva variable, habra alguna forma de que la Variable con el if detecte ya sea miniscula o mayuscula en cualquier letra?

ya sea
MIBancO,
MiBAncO,
Entre Otros, Sin tener que colocar una nueva variable?

Comment: Sí. Convierte el nombre del banco a minúsculas, así como también el contenido que tienes dentro de `Banco`. Algo tipo: `nombre_banco.lower() in (banco.lower() for banco in bancos)`.

Comment: Es mejor que leas la [respuesta completa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison) está en inglés pero está muy bien explicada y te indica como trabajar incluso para [Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/es/)

Comment: Un ejemplo que ponen para que veas la diferencia (y por tanto importancia de contemplar el unicode) que hay es el siguiente
```python
"ß".lower()
#>>> 'ß'

"ß".upper().lower()
#>>> 'ss'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En mi caso yo utilizaría el método `str.lower()`. Por ejemplo, haría algo así:

```
nombre_banco = 'mibanco' 
# O com sea, da igual el contenido, pues luego lo conviertes a minúsculas

if nombre_banco.lower() in Banco.lower():
```

El método `.lower()` lo que hace es convertirte una cadena a minúsculas. Entonces, como las dos cadenas son minúsculas, ya no tendrías el problema que comentas.

Comment: En Python, para poner comentarios, se usa en simbolo # al principio del comentario, no el //

Comment: Gracias @Dante S., es verdad. perdóname, que estaba programando en C# cuando vi la pregunta y se me fue la cabeza por completo. ¡Gracias!

Comment: No hay nada de que disculparse c: Un placer ayudar!